# Algorithm to return all combinations of 3 combinations from a array of length 6 without the number appearing with the same set of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, combinations

I was trying to write a algorithm in javascript that returns all the possible 3 digit numbers numbers from a given array of length 6
For Example

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
```

I have already got the combinations with the same sets of numbers in different positions in the 2D array.
([The code which I took the help of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32171389/12237990))

If I have the same numbers in different combinations then I would like to remove them form the array. like I have `[1, 2, 3]` at index `i` in the array comtaining all the possible combinations then I would like to remove other combination with the same numbers like `[2, 1, 3]`, `[1, 3, 2]` and so on..

> Note the array also contains numbers repeated like `[3, 3, 3]`, `[2, 2, 2]`, `[3, 2, 3]` and so on

I expect an `2d array` which has the values : `[[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,2,5],[1,2,6],[1,3,4]]` and so on (24 possibilities)

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you explicitly state what result you expect from the example array?

Comment: Ok sure I will add That

Comment: I get a 2d array in which the inner array has a fixed length of 3

Comment: what should happen if you got `[3, 3, 3]` as input?

Comment: please add some more examples and the wanted result. actually it is hard to know, if the data has duplicates and what should happen with them and if you like to get all same elementes as well.

Comment: *What* are your 24 possibilities?

Comment: I recommend you to use this lobrary because reasons: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.combinations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32171389/12237990) you linked, just filter out the results with the help of a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

Sort an individual result, convert them into a String using [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), check if it's present in set or not, and if not, then store them in the final result.

```js
function cartesian_product(xs, ys) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < xs.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < ys.length; j++) {
      // transform [ [1, 2], 3 ] => [ 1, 2, 3 ] and append it to result []
      result.push([].concat.apply([], [xs[i], ys[j]]));
    }
  }
  return result;
}

function cartesian_power(xs, n) {
  var result = xs;
  for (var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    result = cartesian_product(result, xs)
  }
  return result;
}

function unique_cartesian_power(xs, n) {
  var result = cartesian_power(xs, n);
  var unique_result = [];
  const set = new Set();

  result.forEach(function(value) {
    var representation = value.sort().join(' ');
    if (!set.has(representation)) {
      set.add(representation);
      unique_result.push(value);
    }

  });

  return unique_result;
}


console.log(unique_cartesian_power([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

const result = arr.reduce((a, v) => arr.reduce((a, v2) => {
 arr.reduce((a, v3) => {
  const current = [v, v2, v3].sort().join(",");
  !a.find(_ => _.sort().join() === current) && a.push([v, v2, v3]);
  return a;
 }, a);
 return a;
}, a), []);

console.log(result.length);
console.log(...result.map(JSON.stringify));
```

Comment: Why `[1,1,1],[1,1,2]...` in the result?

Comment: @vivek_23 it's in OP note

Comment: @ponury-kostek, Ok, if you've took `[1,1,1]`, then where is `[6,6,6]` etc?

Comment: Also missing `[6,6,6]` or `[3,3,3]` as OP says:
_"Note the array also contains numbers repeated like [3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2], [3, 2, 3] and so on"_

Answer (score 0):

You could take an iterative and recursive approach by sorting the index and a temporary array for the collected values.

Because of the nature of going upwards with the index, no duplicate set is created.

```js
function getCombination(array, length) {
    function iter(index, right) {
        if (right.length === length) return result.push(right);
        if (index === array.length) return;
        for (let i = index, l = array.length - length + right.length + 1; i < l; i++) {
            iter(i + 1, [...right, array[i]]);
        }
    }
    var result = [];
    iter(0, []);
    return result;
}

var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    result = getCombination(array, 3);

console.log(result.length);
result.forEach(a => console.log(...a));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Going index wise isn't the right idea. Case where this fails: `[2,1,3,2,4,5]`

Comment: Seems also to miss combinations: e.g. `[6,6,6]`

Comment: @vivek_23, what goes wrong? of duplicate values are not wanted, you could take an array with unique values as input.

Comment: @ChristianUlbrich, why `[6, 6, 6]`?

Comment: @NinaScholz Yours currently returns `[2,1,3]` and `[1,3,2]` as 2 different combinations which was supposed to be removed. We can't remove duplicates because sometimes they do provide a valid combination depending upon the input. Like for `[1,1,2,3,4]`, `[1,1,2]` is a valid combination. I was initially confused by OP's statement at first.

Comment: @NinaScholz `[6,6,6]` is a valid combination; at least this is how I understood OP.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example, that it is usually worthwhile **not asking** for a *specific* answer for a *generic* problem shown with a *specific* question; however as you've requested - *if* you really have the above *constraints* which kind of don't make much sense to me, you could do it like that:

```js
function combine(firstDigits, secondDigits, thirdDigits) {

  let result = [];

  firstDigits.forEach(firstDigit => {
// combine with all secondDigitPermutations
secondDigits.forEach(secondDigit => {
  // combine with all thirdDigitPermutations
  thirdDigits.forEach(thirdDigit => {
    result.push([firstDigit, secondDigit, thirdDigit])
  })
})
  });

  // now we have all permutations and simply need to filter them
  // [1,2,3] is the same as [2,3,1]; so we need to sort them 
  // and check them for equality (by using a hash) and memoize them
  
  // [1,2,3] => '123'
  function hashCombination(combination) {
return combination.join('ಠ_ಠ');
  }

  return result
// sort individual combinations to make them equal
.map(combination => combination.sort())
.reduce((acc, currentCombination) => {
  // transform the currentCombination into a "hash"
  let hash = hashCombination(currentCombination); 
  // and look it up; if it is not there, add it to cache and result
  if (!(hash in acc.cache)) {
    acc.cache[hash] = true;
    acc.result.push(currentCombination);
  } 
  return acc;
  
}, {result: [], cache: {}})
.result;
}

console.log(combine([1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6]).length);
console.log(...combine([1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6]).map(JSON.stringify));
```

This does not include some super-clever assumptions about some index, but it **does** abuse the fact, that it's all about *numbers*. It is deliberately using *no* recursion, because this would easily explode, if the amount of combinations is going to be bigger and because recursion in itself is not very readable.

For *a real world* problem™ - you'd employ a somewhat *similar* strategy though; generating all combinations and then filter them. Doing both at the same time, is an exercise left for the astute reader. For *finding* combinations, that *look* different, but are considered to be the *same* you'd also use some kind of *hashing* and *memoizing*.

Comment: Use a delimiter when joining `combination.join('');`. This is because there could be overlapping joins. Like say we are looking for combinations of length 2. We can have combinations as `[12,3]` and the other as `[1,23]`. Without a delimiter, both would give  `123`.

Comment: Good catch. Luckily it's just a simple change. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
let arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

function getCombination(arr){
    let arr2 = [];
    for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        for(let j=i; j<arr.length; j++){
            for(let k=j; k<arr.length; k++){
                arr2.push([arr[i],arr[j],arr[k]]);
            }   
        }
    }
    return arr2;
}

console.log(getCombination(arr1));
```

Comment: This does not satisfy OP's constraints concerning duplicates.

Comment: can you backup your claim with evidence (an example)?

Comment: you are **right** and I am **wrong**. I was too fast. Amazing, how simple this in the end can be; yours is probably the desired solution to this strange interview question. :) However I cannot upvote again; I am sorry. :(

Comment: i was only wandering if you noticed some mistake in my code that i didn't..i have no problem with  the vote ,but i request you not to rush things in the futur..**continue the good work**

Comment: [1,1,13,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,17]  results with a [2,2,17] subset    

for(let j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++){
for(let k=j+1; k<arr.length; k++){